# CSS effect :hover::after on child element on :hover on parent

Tags: html, jquery, css, hover

I am struggling to get CSS hover effect on the text of a div when I hover on the div.

I want the `.mark-heading` tag text to get underlined via `:hover::after` effect when I hover on the `.card-about` div.

```css
.card-about::after {
  margin: auto;
  padding: 1px 0px;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 3px;
  background: #000000;
  transition: width 0.5s;
}

.card-about:hover::after {
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  transition: width 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<div class="card-about">
  <div class="justify-content-center d-flex">
    <img class="rounded-circle" src="delivery.png" alt="Generic placeholder image" width="140" height="140">
  </div>
  <h4 class="mark-heading">Free Delivery</h4>
  <div class="about-box-content d-block">Some text here</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to apply the underline to the `.mark-heading` element instead, simply change the CSS selectors to target that element instead of `.card-about`:

```css
.mark-heading::after{
  margin: auto;
  padding: 1px 0px;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 3px;
  background: #000000;
  transition: width 0.5s;
}

.card-about:hover .mark-heading::after {
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  transition: width 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<div class="card-about">
  <div class="justify-content-center d-flex">
    <img class="rounded-circle" src="delivery.png" alt="Generic placeholder image" width="140" height="140">
  </div>
  <h4 class="mark-heading">Free Delivery</h4>
  <div class="about-box-content d-block">Some text here</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I want it via a transition effect. When I hover, it expands its width from 0% to !00%. when i mouse out from the div, it shrinks back to 0% width.

Comment: That's what this code is doing, as you can see in the snippet

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite see why you need `:hover::after`.

Add the following lines:

```css
.card-about:hover .mark-heading {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

This selects the `.mark-heading` div **when** `.card-about` is hovered.

```css
.card-about::after {
  margin: auto;
  padding: 1px 0px;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 3px;
  background: #000000;
  transition: width 0.5s;
}

.card-about:hover::after {
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  transition: width 0.3s;
}

.card-about:hover .mark-heading {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<div class="card-about">
  <div class="justify-content-center d-flex">
    <img class="rounded-circle" src="delivery.png" alt="Generic placeholder image" width="140" height="140">
  </div>
  <h4 class="mark-heading">Free Delivery</h4>
  <div class="about-box-content d-block">Some text here</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I want it via a transition effect. When I hover, it expands its width from 0% to !00%. when i mouseout from the div, it shrinks back to 0% width.